# Why budgerigar couple fights each other?

Tags: budgerigar

I have pet budgerigar; one white in color(female) and other parrot color. Taken two months back.

Regarding Parrot Color budgerigar:

When i insert my finger in their cage; the parrot color bird sits on finger and also comes out and allow to touch and fly in room and goes in his cage himself. He sings and dances.

Regarding White budgerigar:

White budgerigar always fight with parrot color budgerigar ; throw him down from stick; bite him. If he is eating; she bite him and start eating food and do not allow him to eat. Also, When i take finger to her she runs away. She try to bite finger. She shouts.

How can i change nature of white budgerigar or should i change it with another female?